# How do I write a function that returns the atomic mass given an element's symbol?

Tags: chemistry

I want to write a function atomMass that, given an element's symbol, say "He", returns the atomic mass for the element (in this case ~ 4.0026). I do not even know where to start with this question. Pleas help.

Comment: I am suppose to write a function that shows the atomic mass of any given elements symbol. I do not know how to write that code

Comment: here is my entire problem, Write a function "alloyDensity" that computes the specific mass (mass per volume) of solid solutions (alloys).

Answer (score 11):

The way to go about solving this problem is:

1. In the Documentation Center, type "atomic mass" into the search field.
2. The 2nd hit on the search results will `ElementData`. Click on it.
3. The 1st example under Basic Examples is

   ```
   ElementData["Carbon", "AtomicWeight"]
   ```

   > `Quantity[12.0107, "AtomicMassUnit"]`

   this gives the hint one needs to get started.
4. It turns out `ElementData` is pretty flexible,

   ```
   ElementData["C", "AtomicMass"]
   ```

   > `Quantity[12.0107, "AtomicMassUnit"]`
5. If you don't want a unitized quantity but just the magitude, write

   ```
    QuantityMagnitude[ElementData["C", "AtomicMass"]]
   ```

   > `12.0107`
6. To make a function, just substitute a variable for the element name in `ElementData`

   ```
   atomMass[atomSymbol_String] := 
     QuantityMagnitude[ElementData[atomSymbol, "AtomicMass"]]

   atomMass["He"]
   ```

   > `4.002602`

Comment: How can I use atomMass this function to calculate the total atomic weight of an alloy? Say, Fe73B13Si9 Thank you!

Comment: @1234. That's not what you asked in your question. Further, you should be able to work that out if you study this answer. And, finally, I'm not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am trying to solve this by myself, and your answer is very helpful. Thank you anyway

Comment: @1234. I'll give a hint. Write a function that takes Fe73B13Si9 as a string and use built-in string and list processing functions to make two lists: `{"Fe", "B", "Si"}` and {73, 13, 9}. Map `atomMass` over the 1st list, then do a dot product.

Comment: I tried for couple hours and I can separate number from string function that I wrote, but I cannot figure out how to get element name, can you help a little for that? Thank you

Comment: @1234. I can supply such a function, but i don't see any use for it. The density of a solid is not related to the atomic mass of its constituent elements in any simple way. For example, Au has a lower atomic mass than Pb, but it is denser.

Answer (score 7):

This does not answer your question but rather offers a visual, albeit less accurate, alternative to a function.

```
{atomicNumber, atomicMass} =
  Panel[
     WolframAlpha[
      "periodic table of the elements",
      {{"PeriodicTableProperties:ElementData", 1},
       "Content"},
      PodStates -> {
        "PeriodicTableProperties:ElementData__Atomic mass",
        "PeriodicTableProperties:ElementData__" <> #}],
     #] & /@
   {"Atomic Number", "Atomic Mass"};

Toggler[atomicMass, {atomicNumber, atomicMass}]
```

which toggles between the following two views.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not realise that Wolfram added the newly discovered elements already.  Very nice.